# .NET Core console app dependency injection - how to configure usage of Newtonsoft.Json for deserializing IOptions<>

Tags: json, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application, settings

Is it possible to configure a .Net Core 3.1 console application to use the Newtonsoft.Json library to  deserialize the IOptions<> (from Microsoft.Extensions.Options) , when reading the sections of a json settings file?

```
 public MyService(IOptions<MyAppDataSettings> MyAppDataOptions)
 {
     var myAppDataOptions = MyAppDataOptions?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(MyAppDataSettings));
 }
```

The result is different from when deserializing directly with System.Text.Json:

```
var appJsonData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyAppDataSettings>(File.ReadAllText(appJsonPath));
```

The settings contain an "ordered" dictionary. When calling directly the deserializer, the order of the keys is correct, as in the json settings file. But the value returned by IOptions<> contains a dictionary with the keys sorted alphabetically.
I tried then to force the usage of NewtonsoftJson:

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });

    services.Configure<MyAppDataSettings>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyAppDataSettings)));
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         new HostBuilder()
             .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
             {
                 ConfigureServices(context.Configuration, services);
             })
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
             {
                 var appExecPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
                 var appSettingsPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(appExecPath, @"Settings"));

                 configurationBuilder
                     .SetBasePath(appSettingsPath)
                     .AddJsonFile("MySettings.json", false);
             });
```

The result when using the Newtonsoft.Json deserializer is the same as with System.Text.Json.

```
var appJsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAppDataSettings>(File.ReadAllText(appJsonPath));
```

So the question is: how are the IOptions< MyAppDataSettings > actually deserialized? I suppose that the "magic" occurs in the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json library.

Answer (score 0):

Neither JSON nor Dictionary guarantees key ordering. As per Dictionary documentation
[MSDN Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Based on my experience I would highly recommend to rethink the approach you uses for configuration and get rid of order dependency.

Comment: You are right, but there are customized OrderedDictionary implementations available, which keep the order of adding the keys. As I said, when deserializing directly this works perfectly with both System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json implementations. It looks that Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json implementation has problems with it. But as I want to keep the IOptions<> dependency injection, I will have to define a class and replace the ordered dictionary with a list of class instances.